Meta Audience Network: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method addNetworkExtrasBundle
So, I'm integrating the Meta Audience Network with mediation in AdMob.
When I'm trying to launch the ad using Mediation Test Suite the app is crashing with
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method addNetworkExtrasBundle(Ljava/lang/Class;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder' appears in /data/app/~~oKlg38Jc4VCuldv5j8yjbw==/in.animall.android-j-38kGYKedQ-_97P08tWkw==/base.apk!classes19.dex)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.utils.AdRequestUtil.buildAdRequest(AdRequestUtil.java:64)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.utils.AdManager.<init>(AdManager.java:26)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.utils.InterstitialAdManager.<init>(InterstitialAdManager.java:19)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.dataobjects.AdFormat$2.createAdLoader(AdFormat.java:27)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.dataobjects.BatchAdRequestManager.testNextConfig(BatchAdRequestManager.java:49)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.dataobjects.BatchAdRequestManager.beginTesting(BatchAdRequestManager.java:39)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.activities.ConfigurationItemDetailActivity.loadSelectedAds(ConfigurationItemDetailActivity.java:240)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.activities.ConfigurationItemDetailActivity.access$500(ConfigurationItemDetailActivity.java:42)
    at com.google.android.ads.mediationtestsuite.activities.ConfigurationItemDetailActivity$2.onMenuItemClick(ConfigurationItemDetailActivity.java:86)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:224)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:769)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:833)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:157)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:984)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:974)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:620)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:155)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7447)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7420)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:837)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28867)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)

When I try to launch the ad with AdMob, it loads, but with Meta Audience Network, it crashes.

Here are the versions of the libraries
facebook-mediation = "6.18.0.0"
playServicesAds = "23.4.0"
mediationTestSuite = "3.0.0"
play-services-ads = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-ads", version.ref = "playServicesAds" }
google-ads-facebook = { group = "com.google.ads.mediation", name = "facebook", version.ref = "facebook-mediation"}
mediation-test-suite = { group = "com.google.android.ads", name = "mediation-test-suite", version.ref = "mediationTestSuite" }


Did you get any solution for this?

No @AsharaliVU. We end up removing Vungle.
